# Can't execute msvsmon.exe from a share for Visual Studio Remote Debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2008, permissions, remote-debugging

I understand remote debugging can be through a Windows share without installing the components on the remote machine (test server in this case)

When accessing my workstation's share `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x86` I can browse files fine. When I try to launch msvsmon.exe, I reveive this error: `Windows cannot access the specified device, path or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item` as if I don't have permission.

But, my dev box share is set to full permissions for **Everyone**. It's wide open as far as I can tell. On the test server (running the app), I am an administrator. Test server is Windows 2003 standard sp2, dev box is xp sp3. I've tried taking ownership of the file--no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to copy the Remote Debugger directory to the server and setup local accounts on both boxes with same username and password.